# How do you remove/delete a mount point in windows

Tags: powershell, wmi, mount-point

I am looking for a way to remove a mount point (with either powershell/wmi/C#). I used the `win32_volume` to find what volumes have mount points and can find the path there (under name and caption) but I can't figure out how to delete those mount points. The `win32_volume` namespace has a method to create them but nothing to delete. The `win32_mountpoints` is read only. Haven't had any luck finding a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) has a Remove-MountPoint cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/powershell-remove-a-drive-mountletter-more-win32/

I converted it to pure powershell so there is no dependencies on external modules.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the powershell commands to remove mount points

```
# remove the mount point
$Driveletter='E'
Get-Volume -Drive $DriveLetter | Get-Partition | Remove-PartitionAccessPath -accesspath "$DriveLetter`:\"
```

Comment: These cmdlets are not available to me (Windows 2008 R2, PowerShell 5).

Comment: @Joost Powershell cmdlets are specific to OS. This cmdlet available from windows 2012 onwards